# When is a good time to double rooks?

Tags: rooks

When analysing my games with an engine (Stockfish 8) I found that I quite frequently miss when the engine thinks it would be a good idea/time to move a rook to the second rank to double up (I guess).

I had a short search on YouTube to find some material on the topic and couldn't find one at first glance.

Do you guys have any recommendations on how to recognise when the position allows/favours bringing rooks into position?

Maybe its a naive question but I'll give it a try anyway since I consider myself somewhat of an intermediate beginner.

Comment: It would help to see the position you are referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider doubling rooks if:

- There is an important open-file, and you want to make sure you have firm control on it. You want to minimize your opponent's controls to the file. (**very common**).
- There is a semi-open file with an isolated or backward pawn. The pawn is protected by your opponent's rook. You want to win it. (**very common**)
- If you want to exchange both rooks.
- If you want to improve the position of your rooks. In particular if no other good squares for the rooks to go.
- You have something to pin on the open-file, and you want to win it (look at the game below)

You may want to study the classical game between Alekhine and Nimzowitsch. Look at the final position:

> http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1012683&kpage=1

[image]

Here, you have absolutely no reason not to double your rooks for both sides. Nimzowitsch had to double to protect his c6 knight. Alekhine had to double his rooks to win the c6 knight. Note there is an open c-file and no any other good squares for the rooks.

Comment: _Double the rooks_ means?

Comment: @KrishnShweta https://www.chess.com/forum/view/game-analysis/doubling-rooks

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to analyze it (I know very few basis of chess nothing much). I assume it means promoting the pawn. Is it?

Comment: @KrishnShweta Do you want to start a new question, something like "what is doubling rooks"? In this question, we focus on **when** not **what**.

Comment: Oh! I'll do little research and then I'll post a question.

Comment: I found the meaning. It's simply the position of the rooks as you have given in image. Thanks for bearing.

Answer (score 2):

There can be all kinds of reasons for moving a rook to the second rank.

- in order to double rooks (and/or queen) on an open or half-open file so that you control the file and can use it for access to the opponent's camp; This is a very common theme and often very strong.
- in order to protect a pawn on the second rank; e.g. in the King's Indian Main line (Mar del Plata variation) black often moves the rook from f8 to f7 where it protects c7, b7...
- in order to make space for another piece; in the same variation, after Rf7, black will often followup with Bf8 so that the bishop protects the d6 pawn
- in order to get to a better square; yet again in the same variation, after Rf7...Bf8 black can play Rg7 from where the rook supports a pawn push of g5-g4.

Answer (score 0):

Doubling of the Rooks in Chess means that you want to capture an Open file . You do doubling because you feel that controlling any open file leads you to a better & faster attack . It exactly paves a Path for attacking your Opponent and keep the attack within your control. I would suggest you to go through some of the Games of Sicilian Dragon Yugoslav Attack where White clears the h-file sacrificing a Pawn and then tries to break open and checkmating Black's monarch . Simultaneously Black sometimes double his rook on c-file and goes for an exchange Sacrifice with Knight .

You can find one game of Nimzovitsch where doubling Rooks on f-file created the infamous Immortal Zugzwang Game . [Immortal Zugzwang Game wiki Explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_Zugzwang_Game)

[Immortal Zugzwang Game](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1102400)